# spread() function used to work, now gives error about object 'as_data_frame.matrix' of mode 'function' was not found

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I was running code from a month ago with the tidyr package's spread() function, and it now throws the error below. Does the code need to be changed, or the package updated?

```
Error in get("as_data_frame.matrix", asNamespace("tibble"), mode = "function") :
object 'as_data_frame.matrix' of mode 'function' was not found
```

I've tried checking that the dataframe is formatted correctly, spelling out the inputs, and with an oversimplified example. Still gives me the same error.

```
#make a new dataframe
x<-c("A","A","B","B")
y<-c("USA","EU","USA","EU")
z<-c(1,2,3,4)
test1<-cbind.data.frame(x,y,z)

#confirm it is a dataframe
str(test1)
test1$y

#try out spread() function
test2<-spread(data=test1,key=y,value=z)
```

outputs this error instead of a re-arranged table

```
Error in get("as_data_frame.matrix", asNamespace("tibble"), mode = "function") :
object 'as_data_frame.matrix' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Is anyone else seeing this happen? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that was trivial. Updated the tidyr package through the R Studio dialog and it works again. Sorry.

```
> test2<-spread(data=test1,key=y,value=z)
> test2
  x EU USA
1 A  2   1
2 B  4   3
```

Comment: Hi Zuzana, do you remember which versions of tidyr you had before and after ? I'm running into the exact same issue, yet updating tidyr doesnt seem to resove it.

Comment: running 0.6.0 at the moment